# Google Maps Encoded Polyline Algorithm Rounded Result Imprecise

Tags: google-maps

I'm using `Google Maps JS API V3` for a project, to add solar panels on house roofs.

The solar panels are very small in size (`0.0000149 latitude and 0.000011 longitude`).

The problem is that the Encoded Polyline Algorithm rounds the coordinates to 5 decimal places. In most cases, this would be accurate enough, but in my case, my polygons are made 50% larger due to the rounding (`0.00002` instead of `0.0000149`).

Is it possible to somehow increase the precision of the algorithm to `6 decimal` places instead of `5`?

Encoded polyline algorithm: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm
(specifically step 2)

Comment: This is a very interesting question but the title could use some polish - it doesn't really give any hint at all about what the question is about. Maybe worth a second look?

Comment: Can you use normal polygons rather than encoded ones?  Changing the resolution of the encoded ones would make them incompatible with the build in decoding and encoding routines.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to encode them, otherwise I run into some other issues with the Google Static Map API.

Comment: Google Static Maps won't support any extended accuracy in the encoding.